# "mixture problem" we have 4 beakers ,we pour a certain amount from two initial bet a final concentration

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Beaker A contains 500 ml of 20% salt solution, and beaker B contains 800 ml of 50% salt solution. A lab
tech pours some of each of these solutions into beakers C and D so that beaker C contains 100 ml of 30%
salt solution, and beaker D contains 200 ml of 45% salt solution. How many milliliters remain in beaker B
after this is done?

It makes sense to take 800 and subtract two precentages of the initial beakers to get the other two percentages, but im confused on what the ratios will be :(
this problem comes off a contest called AMATYC , a 2020 test of 20 multiple choice questions. The authors are highly creative coming up with challenging and 'outside the box ' type questions. I learned that there are ALGEBRA problems out there thats are not just "2 equations , 2 unknowns" , but as this case shows , 4 equations , 4 unknowns, but only needing the 2 you want to know to solve it !

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through the answer in a mathematical fashion. Assume you pour $x$ ml from beaker A and $y$ ml from beaker B in the process of preparing C and D.

We have the volume conservation (as no additional water from outside is introduced)

$$x+y = 300$$

Now, we also have net conservation of the salt, as we are not introducing that either. If we just pour out a solution, it does not change the average concentration of the original solution (assuming homogeneous mixing). Hence

$$0.2x+ 0.5y = 0.3(100) + 0.45(200)$$

Now you can solve these two equations for $x,y$ and hence obtain the amount remaining in $B$ as $(800-y)$

Comment: so what is the answer Dhanvi ? according to your equations the answer is not 600

Comment: There's probably a mistake or a typo in the question, I don't think you can prepare the C and D solutions as given without introducing additional salt/water

Comment: the last equation will be 'golden' when you add .2z+ .5w to left side ..then z+w to the top one :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of measurements that you need to track:  the first is the volume, and the second is the amount of salt in the solution.  Notice that I didn't say the *concentration* of salt, but the actual amount, because concentration is expressed as a percentage of the volume, so for example, 50% salt in a 100 ml beaker is 50 ml of salt, but 50% salt in a 500 ml beaker is 250 ml of salt.  So concentration is harder to work with because the same percentage can mean different amounts of salt depending on the volume of the solution.

Everything falls into place one you understand this.  Convert all of your concentrations into amounts of salt, so Beaker A contains $(0.2)(500) = 100$ ml of salt; Beaker B contains $(0.5)(800) = 400$ ml of salt; Beaker $C$ contains $30$ ml, and Beaker D contains $90$ ml.

If the lab tech poured $x$ ml of solution from Beaker B into Beaker C, and $y$ ml of solution from Beaker B into Beaker D, then several things are true:

1. Volumes must be conserved:  $100 - x$ is the amount of volume poured from Beaker A to C, and $200 - y$ is the amount poured from Beaker A to D.
2. The total amount of salt transferred from Beaker B to C is $0.5x$, and the total amount of salt transferred from Beaker B to D is $0.5y$.
3. Amounts of salt must be conserved:  $30 - 0.5x$ ml of salt was poured from Beaker A to C, and $90 - 0.5y$ ml of salt was poured from Beaker A to D.
4. The volumes and amounts of salt poured from A to C and D must be consistent with the concentration of salt in Beaker A.  What this means is that if $100 - x$ volume was poured from A to C, $20\%$ of this volume is equal to the amount of salt poured from A to C.  But we said this was $30 - 0.5x$ ml salt.  So

$$(0.2)(100 - x) = 30 - 0.5x.$$

Similarly, $$(0.2)(200 - y) = 90 - 0.5y.$$

Once you solve for $x$ and $y$, the total volume remaining in Beaker B is simply $800 - x - y$.

Comment: Yeah, if you solve the system, it doesn't give you meaningful answers.. I'm guessing there is some error in the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try considering how much of a mixture would be equivalent (e.g. containing the same amount of salt) to a smaller volume of a $100\%$ salt solution.

Suppose $x$ and $y$ represent how much solution is pouring into beaker $C$ from beakers $A$ and $B$, respectively. Similarly, $z$ and $w$ represent how much solution is pouring into beaker $D$ from beakers $A$ and $B$.

The total volume of beakers $C$ and $D$ are represented by the equations ....
$$\begin{align}
x+y &= 100\\
z+w &= 200\\
\end{align}$$

And the $100\%$ salt solution equivalencies are indicated by ...
$$\begin{align}
0.2x+0.5y &= (0.3)(100)\\
0.2z+0.5w &= (0.45)(200)\\
\end{align}$$

This system of equations gives us solutions $3x=200$, $3y=100$, $3z=100$, and $3w=500$. The amount of solution left in beaker $B$ would be $800-y-w = 800 - \frac{3y+3w}{3} = 800-\frac{100+500}{3}=800-200=600$ml.

Comment: Yep I get it thanks to your most clear solution John Joy! one of the few algebra problems you have to take the leap into what seems like too deep of water ..4 unknowns & 4 equations ( not like Dhanvi's solution with only 2 ) . solving for the unknowns of y and w was not all that tough swimming lol . thanks again im awarding yours best answer !